# How to move office

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I've just developed a massively successful game in game dev tycoon but turned down the offer to move into the large office building because I didn't have that much money. After the game was released I earned a massive amount of money and am now ready to move into the technology park. However, I can't find an option to do this. How do I move office if I've turned down the previous offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game will ask you again if you want to move every 5 months.

---

From codeNw.js:

```
(!a.flags.lastMoveUpLevelQ||a.flags.lastMoveUpLevelQ<=GameManager.gameTime-2E4*GameManager.SECONDS_PER_WEEK)
```

The game prompts the notification only if you never declined it, or if the last time you declined was `2E4*GameManager.SECONDS_PER_WEEK` ticks ago.

From codeNw.js again:

```
b.SECONDS_PER_WEEK=4;
```

Now, some maths.

- There are 1000 ticks in a second, so 80000 ticks are equivalent to 80 seconds.
- There are 4 seconds in a week, so 80 seconds are equivalent to 20 weeks.
- There are 4 weeks in a month, so 20 weeks are equivalent to 5 months.

Note that the above calculations are the same for all possible moves in the game.